# memcpy a substring

Tags: c, substring, memcpy

I would like to try **C memcpy** function. I have this code:

```
char destination[40];
memcpy(destination, "My favorite destination is...", 11);
printf(destination);
```

I woul like to copy first 11 letters to destination array. When I use printf, the result is "My favorite2". Why?

Comment: Why do you use `memcpy` for strings? Why not `strncpy`?

Comment: @KerrekSB `strncpy(destination, "My favorite destination is...", 11);` wouldn't add a NUL byte either.

Comment: @rodrigo: Good point. How silly. Maybe `strncat`?

Comment: in this simple case just initializing the array would even be a better strategy. Then it'd work perfectly with `memcpy`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are missing the NULL terminator at the end of the 11 characters -> Printf is just printing whatever is in that part of memory until it finds a NULL terminator.

Simply add in destination[11] = 0;

That should work :)

Answer (score 3):

That is because `memcpy` does not terminate the string with a null byte. You could start by filling the entire array with nulls:

```
memset(destination, 0, sizeof destination);
```

Answer (score 3):

C strings must be null terminated. Simplest solution is to copy 0's into the whole string first.

```
memset(destination, 0, sizeof(destination));
```

Comment: no the simplest is just to initialize the array correctly from the start `char destination[40] = { 0 };` would do it.

Answer (score 0):

```
printf("%.11s","My favorite destination is...");
```